# Django On Openshift DYI Cartridge

Tags: django, jenkins, openshift

I have followed this tutorial https://github.com/joskid/openshift-diy-py27-django-jenkins and everything went until I uploaded the project to openshift the jenkins build fails and when I browse the app url it shows service not available. I am not really sure what happend and how to fix that. 
this is the build log

```
        Started by user Jenkins Admin
    Building remotely on mysitebldr in workspace /var/lib/openshift/5317c6ee50044663e000036a/app-root/runtime/repo
    Checkout:repo / /var/lib/openshift/5317c6ee50044663e000036a/app-root/runtime/repo - hudson.remoting.Channel@459854:mysitebldr
    Using strategy: Default
    Last Built Revision: Revision 31a96e01750490afe87bebc10e9372dcff40100c (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
    Checkout:repo / /var/lib/openshift/5317c6ee50044663e000036a/app-root/runtime/repo - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@22a54
    Wiping out workspace first.
    Cloning the remote Git repository
    Cloning repository origin
    Fetching upstream changes from ssh://5317bd0c5973ca2b12000001@mysite-ysedera.rhcloud.com/~/git/mysite.git
    Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
    Seen branch in repository origin/master
    Commencing build of Revision 31a96e01750490afe87bebc10e9372dcff40100c (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
    Checking out Revision 31a96e01750490afe87bebc10e9372dcff40100c (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
    Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
    [repo] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7814626151945851430.sh
    + source /usr/lib/openshift/cartridge_sdk/bash/sdk
    ++ '[' false == true ']'
    ++ OO_BASH_SDK=true
    + alias 'rsync=rsync --delete-after -az -e '\''/usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh'\'''
    + upstream_ssh=5317bd0c5973ca2b12000001@mysite-ysedera.rhcloud.com
    + rm -f /var/lib/openshift/5317c6ee50044663e000036a//app-deployments/current/metadata.json
    + marker_present force_clean_build
    + '[' -f /var/lib/openshift/5317c6ee50044663e000036a/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/markers/force_clean_build ']'
    + set +e
    + rsync --delete-after -az -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh '5317bd0c5973ca2b12000001@mysite-ysedera.rhcloud.com:$OPENSHIFT_BUILD_DEPENDENCIES_DIR' /var/lib/openshift/5317c6ee50044663e000036a/app-root/runtime/build-dependencies/
    + rsync --delete-after -az -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh '5317bd0c5973ca2b12000001@mysite-ysedera.rhcloud.com:$OPENSHIFT_DEPENDENCIES_DIR' /var/lib/openshift/5317c6ee50044663e000036a/app-root/runtime/dependencies/
    + set -e
    + gear build
    Building git ref 'origin/HEAD', commit 31a96e0
    + /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh 5317bd0c5973ca2b12000001@mysite-ysedera.rhcloud.com 'gear stop --conditional --exclude-web-proxy --git-ref 31a96e01750490afe87bebc10e9372dcff40100c'
    Stopping gear...
    Stopping DIY cartridge
    ++ /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh 5317bd0c5973ca2b12000001@mysite-ysedera.rhcloud.com 'gear create-deployment-dir'
    + deployment_dir=2014-03-05_20-05-48.837
    + rsync --delete-after -az -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh /var/lib/openshift/5317c6ee50044663e000036a//app-deployments/current/metadata.json 5317bd0c5973ca2b12000001@mysite-ysedera.rhcloud.com:app-deployments/2014-03-05_20-05-48.837/metadata.json
    + rsync --delete-after -az -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh --exclude .git /var/lib/openshift/5317c6ee50044663e000036a/app-root/runtime/repo/ 5317bd0c5973ca2b12000001@mysite-ysedera.rhcloud.com:app-root/runtime/repo/
    + rsync --delete-after -az -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh /var/lib/openshift/5317c6ee50044663e000036a/app-root/runtime/build-dependencies/ 5317bd0c5973ca2b12000001@mysite-ysedera.rhcloud.com:app-root/runtime/build-dependencies/
    + rsync --delete-after -az -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh /var/lib/openshift/5317c6ee50044663e000036a/app-root/runtime/dependencies/ 5317bd0c5973ca2b12000001@mysite-ysedera.rhcloud.com:app-root/runtime/dependencies/
    + /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh 5317bd0c5973ca2b12000001@mysite-ysedera.rhcloud.com 'gear remotedeploy --deployment-datetime 2014-03-05_20-05-48.837'
    Preparing build for deployment
    Deployment id is ad5722d4
    Activating deployment
    Starting DIY cartridge
    bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 759]
    Error deploying to gear
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
    Archiving artifacts
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its having trouble binding to a socket.

`bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 759]`

I'm looking into it some more but I would suggest that you notify the maintainers and this looks to be a bug with the cart.